# How to linearly weight components of a multiplication?

Tags: weights

I have a composite score that is made up of the multiplication of many components.

I would like to weight each component individually.

example:

```py
   score_a, score_b, score_c = 0.1, 0.2, 0.3
   weight_a, weight_b, weight_c = 0.25, 0.5, 0.25
```

I can weight individual components like this:

```py
   composite_score = (score_a ** weight_a) * (score_b ** weight_b) * (score_c ** weight_c)
```

My problem is that this is not very intuitive as the effect of eg.: `weight_a` (0.25) is not half as big as that of `weight_b` (0.5).

Is there a well working method that let's me weight individual components of a multiplication, while retaining the same relationship between weights and between their effect?

Comment: Multiplying components together is already quite unintuitive. If you take logarithms, your exponential weights turn into "normal" weights for sums of logarithmized scores. (Which will be negative, just like the total score on a log scale.) Why do you want to use products?

Comment: I'm using products, so that the entire composite score becomes 0.0 if a component is 0.0

Comment: Thanks for the idea with the logarithms!